# 404 error system>config>new module

Tags: magento-1.9, xml, configuration

I'm trying to setup a section in system>configuration for an existing module which doesn't yet have a section there. This is my first time doing this so I may have missed something.

adminhtml.xml (the code I've added is in between the  tags:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<menu>
    <factoryx_menu>
        <title>Factory X</title>
        <sort_order>85</sort_order>
        <children>
            <factoryx_notification module="factoryx_notificationboard">
                <title>Notification</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <factoryx_notification_new module="factoryx_notificationboard">
                        <title>Add New Notification</title>
                        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/notificationboard/new/</action>
                    </factoryx_notification_new>
                    <factoryx_notification_list module="factoryx_notificationboard">
                        <title>View Notifications</title>
                        <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                        <action>adminhtml/notificationboard/index/</action>
                    </factoryx_notification_list>
                </children>
            </factoryx_notification>
        </children>
    </factoryx_menu>
</menu>
<acl>
    <resources>
        <admin>
            <children>
                <factoryx_menu>
                    <children>
                        <factoryx_notification>
                            <title>Notification</title>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <factoryx_notification_new>
                                    <title>Add New Notification</title>
                                    <sort_order>10</sort_order>
                                </factoryx_notification_new>
                                <factoryx_notification_list>
                                    <title>View Notifications</title>
                                    <sort_order>20</sort_order>
                                </factoryx_notification_list>
                            </children>
                        </factoryx_notification>
                    </children>
                </factoryx_menu>
            </children>
            <children>
              <system>
                <children>
                  <config>
                    <children>
                      <factoryx_notificationboard>
                        <title>Notification Board</title>
                      </factoryx_notificationboard>
                    </children>
                  </config>
                </children>
              </system>
            </children>                                           
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

config.xml (bit i added in between  tags):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config>
<modules>
    <FactoryX_NotificationBoard>
        <version>1.0.19</version>
    </FactoryX_NotificationBoard>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <factoryx_notificationboard>
            <class>FactoryX_NotificationBoard_Model</class>
          <resourceModel>factoryx_notificationboard_resource</resourceModel>
        </factoryx_notificationboard>
        <factoryx_notificationboard_resource>
            <class>FactoryX_NotificationBoard_Model_Resource</class>
            <entities>
                <notification>
                    <table>fx_notification</table>
                </notification>
            </entities>
        </factoryx_notificationboard_resource>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <factoryx_notificationboard>
            <class>FactoryX_NotificationBoard_Block</class>
        </factoryx_notificationboard>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <factoryx_notificationboard>
            <class>FactoryX_NotificationBoard_Helper</class>
        </factoryx_notificationboard>
    </helpers>
    <resources>
        <factoryx_notificationboard_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>FactoryX_NotificationBoard</module>
            </setup>
        </factoryx_notificationboard_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
<frontend>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <factoryx_notificationboard>
                <file>factoryx/notification.xml</file>
            </factoryx_notificationboard>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <FactoryX_NotificationBoard before="Mage_Adminhtml">FactoryX_NotificationBoard_Adminhtml</FactoryX_NotificationBoard>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
<default>
    <notificationboard>
        <notification_settings>
            <rotatenotifications>1</rotatenotifications>
        </notification_settings>
    </notificationboard>
</default>
```

system.xml (i made the whole file):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<tabs>
    <factoryx translate="label" module="factoryx_notificationboard">
        <label>Factory X</label>
        <sort_order>101</sort_order>
    </factoryx>
</tabs>                                                                               
<sections>
    <notificationboard translate="label" module="factoryx_notificationboard">
    <label>Notification Board</label>
    <tab>factoryx</tab>
    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
    <groups>
        <notification_settings translate="label" module="factoryx_notificationboard">
            <label>Notification Settings</label>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>10</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
            <fields>
                <rotatenotifications translate="label">
                    <label>Rotate Notification Messages</label>
                    <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                    <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>0</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                </rotatenotifications>
            </fields>
        </notification_settings>
    </groups>
    </notificationboard>
</sections>
```

I've managed to get "Notification Board" to show in system>config, but when I click it I get taken to a 404 error. I thought this might be a permission issue, but I changed the file permissions and it didn't help.

I also tried clearing cache and sessions as I read that could be a possible cause.

I've ensured that my role is set to administrator and I have all access.

Thanks so much for taking the time for this

Answer (score 0):

Upon posting this question I proof read it and noticed I had notificationboard instead of factoryx_notificationboard in some places, I've adjusted that and it fixed the issue.